# Complexity and number of bits of square root number

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, numerical-algorithms

Let an integer `a`, and `b` is the number of bits `a`.

1) If I have a number `s = sqrt(a)`, the number of bits `s` will be up to `b/2`?

Considering the code:

```
while (i <= sqrt(a)) {
    if (a % i == 0) return i;
    i++;
}
```

2) The complexity is $O(\sqrt{a})$. But in terms of bits? $O(2^{b/2})$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1):

When you are measuring bits, the complexity is of the form $O(log(b))$ since the number of bits increases at a log rate.

Intuitively, think of the number 10 and 1000. 10 = 1010 and 1000 = 1111101000. The number increases 100-fold but the number of bits only increases a little over two fold. Your hypothesis: $O(2^{b/2})$ is an overestimate.